# How to reset Search Console Indexing to reflect correct reports?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

My Search Console is old. It has been reflecting links and errors dating back to URLs from 2013/2015. In the new website, I have configured everything correctly and made sure there are no internal links pointing out for any old/dead URLs.

Summary of GSC:

[image: GSC Summary]

The problem is, with the errors, it just says "Validation Passed/Started" but when I inspect the pages, it does not show an error?

PS: I have read the similar questions and understand that if there are soft 404 or not found that keep coming up with old URLs, important ones have to be 301 Redirected. I have did that but still I get these errors. Submitted them in the "removal tools" as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Summary:**

You cannot reset Search Console to reflect correct indexing since the report will be the same. (Found the answer after checking with others, Regarding 404, Check "Tony Mc Creath" Answer)

**Notes:**

The new Search Console shows aggregated data reports which are not accurate as of the time being.

Whenever the Search Console logs errors, it is best recommended to check and validate them at the earliest. The Search Console takes it own time, typically 15-45 days to complete the request and mark it accordingly if the problem is fixed.

If the Errors still show "Processing", all you can do it wait until it is marked as "Passed". If the issue is not completed for a long time, the problem should be inspected and checked for which errors/landing pages are listed under "pending" and take necessary action.

> Any notice that is not listed under error or warning or issue can be ignored unless it makes sense to fix things which are available at disposal.

Answer (score 2):

The error type will still be reported for some time, however now you have zero pages with that error (see column to the right). So you have passed and fixed all pages with that error.

A 404 or soft 404 on it's own is not an error. The concern is that it was submitted by some method (sitemap, link from another page) which means there is an issue with either the sitemap or linking.

You can redirect 404s to a relevant page. The page will then not be a 404 but will be reported as excluded because the page redirects. Using redirects can often improve the users experience or help search engines understand changes in a website.

Comment: 1. Regarding your answer: I have seen that. But the same errors keep appearing from time to time with the exact URLs, even though they have been fixed.

2. The pages that are appearing as "Not found", they belong to a 2013 version of the website. I have no idea why they are appearing now. (Example: previous site used to have url structures .aspx, after 2013, we dropped them. Now they are being shown as not found.)

3. I know doing a 301 redirect for these pages can fix the problem. But doesn't doing many 301 bad for SEO?

Comment: 4. When I inspect the pages, which are under pending; the error that they show is fixed. However, it still is under pending.

5. I have updated the sitemap multiple times to reflect the changes as well as you say it might be from linking.

Comment: The reports are often out of sync. Maybe those errors keep coming back because Googlebot knows something is still linking to those missing pages. Google does not care about how many redirects you create. It's redirects to redirects to redirects that can have a negative effect.

Comment: If the reports are often out of sync, I guess I should not worry about them as I am sure we are following everything correctly. Regarding those not found URLs that keep popping up, they should be from previous SEO dating back to 2011, 13. A disavow should do the job I believe.

Comment: disavow is for something completely different. Dodgy backlinks to your site. You may have meant disallow in the robots.txt. That is inappropriate as well. It stops crawling, and you want bots to crawl those pages to discover they are missing, noindexed, redirected, fixed etc.